# AWS Stepfunctions Result Path - Append to JSON instead of nesting

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Currently, I am attempting to create a series of Lambdas that will execute given specific payloads from the StepFunctions Input. I have everything working; however, it's not as I intended.

I finally have grasped the differences between InputPath, ResultPath, and OutputPath. The only problem I have now is allowing the ResultPath to 'append' the returned JSON rather than nesting it within the payload.

Here is the state machine:

```
{
  "StartAt": "GetDailyEmails",
  "States": {
    "GetDailyEmails": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:region:account:function:DailyEmailExtractor",
      "InputPath": "$.GetDailyEmailsInputs",
      "ResultPath": "$.TransformEmailsToCSVInputs.GetDailyEmailsResults",
      "Next": "TransformEmailsToCSV"
    },
    "TransformEmailsToCSV": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:region:account:function:EmailTransform",
      "InputPath": "$.TransformEmailsToCSVInputs",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the input I'm providing:

```
{
    "GetDailyEmailsInputs": {
        "secret_name": "email_password",
        "subject_contains": "stuff",
        "json_output_file_name": "test_emails",
        "bucket_name": "emails"
    },
    "TransformEmailsToCSVInputs": {
        "csv_output_file_name": "email_errors"
    }
}
```

Here was the output I received:

```
{
  "GetDailyEmailsInputs": {
    "secret_name": "email_password",
    "subject_contains": "stuff",
    "json_output_file_name": "test_emails",
    "bucket_name": "emails"
  },
  "TransformEmailsToCSVInputs": {
    "csv_output_file_name": "apex_errors",
    "GetDailyEmailsResults": {
      "object_key": "raw_emails/test_emails.json",
      "bucket_name": "emails"
    }
  }
}
```

While this does work, I have to manually extract out the `GetDailyEmailsResults` in the TransformEmailsToCSV lambda. I wanted to make the lambdas fully agnostic to whether or not they're being executed from a test payload or the stepfunctions.

Here is the output I'm trying to receive:

```
{
  "GetDailyEmailsInputs": {
    "secret_name": "email_password",
    "subject_contains": "stuff",
    "json_output_file_name": "test_emails",
    "bucket_name": "emails"
  },
  "TransformEmailsToCSVInputs": {
    "csv_output_file_name": "apex_errors",
    "object_key": "raw_emails/test_emails.json",
    "bucket_name": "emails"
  }
}
```

This way, there is not a `GetDailyEmailsResults` nested dictionary where I need to account for it.

I could write this in a generalized way where it's just a `data` payload being passed to it; however, I'm trying to just have everything within a single payload without nesting if that's possible.

Answer (score 3):

I can see that you are trying to achieve a good design. Though there is no out of box solution to provide what you need, I have a different proposal that you might want to consider.

1. Put `GetDailyEmailsResults` differently and not in the input that you provided.
2. Create input to lambda from step function data by picking them from the JSON as required.

Here is the state machine that I am proposing(It may not be completely correct syntactically but you will get an idea).

```
{
  "StartAt": "GetDailyEmails",
  "States": {
    "GetDailyEmails": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:region:account:function:DailyEmailExtractor",
      "InputPath": "$.GetDailyEmailsInputs",
      "ResultPath": "$.GetDailyEmailsResults",
      "Next": "TransformEmailsToCSV"
    },
    "TransformEmailsToCSV": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters":{  
            "FunctionName":"EmailTransform",
            "Payload":{  
               "csv_output_file_name": "apex_errors",
               "object_key.$": "$.GetDailyEmailsResults.object_key",
               "bucket_name.$": "$.GetDailyEmailsResults.bucket_name"
            }
         },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

[Have a look at the `Intrinsic functions` of the amazon state language.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-json-manipulate).

You can use `JsonMerge` to achieve what you desire.
Beware that it does not work in the data flow simulator.

You can however use a dummy machine consisting of `Pass` states to simulate and play around.

Unfortunately intrinsic functions are not allowed everywhere.
At the bottom of the linked docs above is a table telling where you can use them.

[image: Screenshot of the aws docs where intrinsic functions may be used]

Comment: can you use `States.JsonMerge` in the `ResultPath`?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'll update my answer to point that out.

Comment: The workaround I’ve found was to use the “Pass” step function type to manipulate data and use States.JsonMerge there